# World Congress Emergency Proposal UI options: "pass" or "add proposals"

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

Civilization 6 Gathering Storm added a World Congress which you can sometimes propose Emergency Proposals and when this happens you get two options "pass" or "add proposals" What does *pass* or *add proposals* mean... it isn't clear to me what "pass" actually means... does it mean you want it or don't want it?

Comment: I was a bit thrown by the double meaning of "pass" as well. Obvious in hindsight, but certainly not so obvious as to warrant all these downvotes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the implementation of the "pass" button was an oversight. Add Proposal means you will spend 30 diplomatic points to suggest the emergency vote. Hitting the pass button has the same effect as hitting the X button on the top right, you can still go back in and "submit" the proposal.

The issue here is "pass" can mean to "pass aside" or "pass" as in nominate... it appears that the use of the word pass here actually meant pass aside.